# Template run fails on project update in AWX 3.0.0.0

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

AWX version: 3.0.0.0

Ansible version: 2.7.6

Host OS: CentOS 7.6.1810

I get an error when updating the project when running a template in AWX:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site- 
packages/awx/main/tasks.py", line 939, in run 
self.pre_run_hook(instance, **kwargs) File 
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site- 
packages/awx/main/tasks.py", line 1424, in pre_run_hook 
project_update_task().run(local_project_sync.id) File 
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site- 
packages/awx/main/tasks.py", line 620, in _wrapped return f(self, 
*args, **kwargs) File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site- 
packages/awx/main/tasks.py", line 1083, in run raise 
AwxTaskError.TaskError(instance, rc) Exception: project_update 1836 
(failed) encountered an error (rc=2), please see task stdout for 
details.
```

Used tower-cli to monitor the job and the stdout:

```
*** DETAILS: Requesting a copy of job standard output 
*************************
GET https://[redacted]/api/v2/jobs/1837/stdout/
Params: {'content_format': 'ansi', 'content_encoding': 'base64', 
'format': 'json'}

------End of Standard Out Stream--------
Error: Job failed.
```

Nothing meaningful.  However, I can update the project manually and it successfully completes.  It is just when the template run calls for a project update, it fails.

I've tried stopping and removing the awx_task container in Docker, and doing a re-install (same version) over the top of the existing installation.  Same error.

I had been happily running jobs this morning, and then it up and died like this.  No changes made in between the time it was working and the time began to fail.

Anyone have any suggestions to try to remedy this?  Thank you!

NOTE: the project update job triggered by the template actually succeeds. It shows successful in the jobs list. But the job generated by the template fails, and shows that the project update failed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with some help from my friends:

A messed up requirements.yml in the repo caused this.

Comment: I have an almost identical error.  How did you trace back to requirements.yml?  I don't see any reference to yml in the original post.